# VBS regexp replace insert character into many similar phrases

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am looking for these strings inside a text file;

LON1     129.97579956

LAT1     -26.33283424

LON2     130.10830688

LAT2     -26.33283424

The names and numbers are separated by a tab and space. I want to insert an "=" between the tab and space.

ie: LON1    = 129.97579956

I can find all four variants with

```
re.pattern = "(LON|LAT)\d\t\s"
```

but how do I insert the "="?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the pattern more specific and use 2 capture groups.

In the replacement use the 2 groups and add an equals sign in between.

```
\b((?:LON|LAT)\d\t)(\s-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:LON|LAT)\d\t` Match either LON or LAT, a digit *(Use `\d+` to match 1+ digits)* and a tab
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\s-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match a whitespace char, optional `-` and 1+ digits with an optional decimal par
- `)` Close group 2
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ROODFB/1)

Comment: Wow. I have never used groups before. I feel I just double my regex capabilities.